# Python display a notification with a visible timeout

Tags: python, python-3.x, notifications

Please note: this is a self answered question for reference.

Using Python how does one display a notification:
a) with a timeout and
b) have the timeout visibly countdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Just 2 weeks after posting this, I updated to Mint 19 (Ubuntu 18.04) the result, the timer function described below has vanished in the Standard Notification. I can only suppose that the move to GTK+3 has virtually hidden the timer. It is there but barely visible.
Choosing Notification style Nodoka or Coco in Control Centre --> Popup Notifications, does display the timer properly.
**End Update**

Using the standard notification modules `notify2` and `Notify` in the `gi.repository`, one simply has to add an action, even though you have no intention of using it.
Note: there appears to be no documented reason for this, that I have found.
In addition to a close button being added to the notification, it also supplies a clockface that reduces based on the timeout supplied.
for `notify2`:

```
import notify2

class Notify():
    def mess_callback():
        pass

    def __init__(self,parent,caption,msg,timeout=None,urgency=None):
        if timeout != None: pass
        else: timeout = 0 # message should not timeout

        if urgency: pass
        else: urgency = 0

        img = '/home/rolf/MyApp.png'
        caps = notify2.get_server_caps()    
        mess = notify2.Notification(caption,msg,img) # passing an image is optional
        mess.set_timeout(timeout) #milliseconds
        mess.set_urgency(urgency) #0-Low, 1-Normal, 2-Critical
        # Without the following `add_action` option, No countdown to the time out is shown
        if timeout != 0 and 'actions' in caps:
            mess.add_action("close","Close",self.mess_callback,None) #Show the countdown to close
        mess.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    notify2.init("MyApp") #Register MyApp

    Notify(None,"Error","This message is not timed and has to be manually cancelled")
    Notify(None,"Error 2","This message will timeout after the default value",timeout=-1)
    Notify(None,"Information","An Unimportant message",timeout=20000,urgency=0)
    Notify(None,"Attention","An Important message",timeout=20000,urgency=1)
    Notify(None,"Emergency","A Critical message",timeout=20000,urgency=2)

    notify2.uninit() #Un-register
```

Using `Notify` in the `gi.repository`:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Notify', '0.7')
from gi.repository import Notify

class Message():
    def mess_callback():
        pass

    def __init__(self,parent,caption,msg,timeout=None,urgency=None):
        if timeout != None: pass
        else: timeout = 0 # message should not timeout

        if urgency: pass
        else: urgency = 0

        img = '/home/rolf/MyApp.png'
        caps = Notify.get_server_caps()    
        mess = Notify.Notification.new(caption, msg, img) # passing an image is optional
        mess.set_timeout(timeout) #milliseconds
        mess.set_urgency(urgency) #0-Low, 1-Normal, 2-Critical
        # Without the following `add_action` option, No countdown to the time out is shown
        if timeout != 0 and 'actions' in caps:
            mess.add_action("close","Close",self.mess_callback,None) #Show the countdown to close
        mess.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Notify.init("MyApp") #Register MyApp

    Message(None,"Error","This message is not timed and has to be manually cancelled")
    Message(None,"Error 2","This message will timeout after the default value",timeout=-1)
    Message(None,"Information","An Unimportant message",timeout=20000,urgency=0)
    Message(None,"Attention","An Important message",timeout=20000,urgency=1)
    Message(None,"Emergency","A Critical message",timeout=20000,urgency=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, in python 3.x, when I set to timeout = 0, notification does not remain forever in Ubuntu 18.04. Any idea?

Comment: @asevindik Not really. I run Mint 19 which is Ubuntu under the bonnet and I've just tried both 0 and None, both work fine, with python3. I can only assume it's connected to the Desktop or Theme that you're running. I can only suggest, you use an inordinately large timeout.

Comment: I see your point but I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and python 3.6.9. I wouldn't expect any problem in such a famous distro. But this is the case. I am now using notification with large timeout :(